# Why are these connections not classified as "established" under conntrack?

Tags: iptables, tcp, timeout

I have the following rule for `iptables`:

```
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

such that outgoing connections not classified as established will be logged. Occasionally, the firewall egress log would capture such packets:

```
09:56:48 DST=a.b.167.208 TTL=64 SPT=80 DPT=25960 WINDOW=119 ACK URGP=0
09:48:48 DST=a.b.166.231 TTL=64 SPT=80 DPT=29861 WINDOW=119 ACK PSH URGP=0
09:29:57 DST=a.b.167.244 TTL=64 SPT=80 DPT=58244 WINDOW=119 ACK URGP=0
```

Upon further examination, the web server access log reveals that there are incoming connections corresponding to the above IP addresses 75-100s earlier on.

Why are the above connections not classified as established by conntrack module? And what could be done to filter out the noise?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a bit more of your IPTables rules for context.. Especially the logging rules. :)  Feel free to sanitize addresses, of course!

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, that's the 1st rule on my firewall output and the remaining rules do not target port 80.

Comment: But do they fold in port 80 as TCP rules?  general IP or TCP rules, for example?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, a TCP connection only enters `ESTABLISHED` state *after* the `ACK` has gone through, and the `ACK` packages are exactly what you seem to be logging (and blocking) there.

http://www.iptables.info/en/connection-state.html#TCPCONNECTIONS

Have you tried `--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED`?

On only logging that "occasionally" as you said: dmesg/syslog won't capture all packets. If too many similar messages come in, they'll be discarded to avoid log flooding. That's configurable, but is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I don't think the problem occurs during the initial TCP 3-way handshake as suggested in the 1st paragraph of your answer since it is the ACK and not the SYN/ACK packets that are being blocked. Also, I have accepted RELATED connections in addition to the ESTABLISHED ones, but that does not solve the problem at all. Sorry, I didn't catch your final point. Occasionally, in the context of my question, means 5-10 such errors per day.